# libgdx - Having trouble establishing my objects to move around?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently working on an android project for practice and I'm having trouble moving the paddles around by touch, like having them scroll from left to right. I thought about using Gdx.input.isTouched but sadly doesn't seem to work very well in my own experience any suggestions or examples would be really appreciated? this is all I have hopefully this may be able to clarify on the subject

```
private void updatePaddle2(float dt) {
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched(0)){
        paddle1.move(-350, 0);

        paddle1.Intergrate(dt);

    }


private void update(float dt) {


    //paddle update
    updatePaddle1(dt);
    updatePaddle2(dt);

}


private void resetRectangle(){
    paddle1.move((field.width * .5f), field.y + (field.height * .1f));
    paddle2.move((field.width * .5f), field.y + (field.height * .8f));
}
```

and the class for the paddles

```
public class Paddle extends GameShare{

private ShapeRenderer paddleRenderer;
Color paddleColor = new Color();


protected Paddle() {
    super(100, 32);
}

public void paddleCreate(){
    paddleRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

}

public void paddleRender(float dt){
    paddleRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    paddleColorSwap(dt);
    drawPaddle(dt);
    paddleRenderer.end();
}

private void drawPaddle(float dt) {
    paddleRenderer.rect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    paddleRenderer.rect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

}


int threshold = 7000;
long LastChanged = 0;
public void paddleColorSwap(float dt){
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - LastChanged < threshold)
        return;
    int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 6);
    switch(rnd){
    case 0: paddleColor.set(Color.GREEN);break;
    case 1: paddleColor.set(Color.BLUE);break;
    case 2: paddleColor.set(Color.RED);break;
    case 3: paddleColor.set(Color.YELLOW);break;
    case 4: paddleColor.set(Color.CYAN);break;
    case 5: paddleColor.set(Color.ORANGE);break;
    }
    LastChanged = System.currentTimeMillis();
    paddleRenderer.setColor(paddleColor);

}

}
```

and the extended class

```
public abstract class GameShare {

private Vector2 position = new Vector2(); 
private Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
private Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();


protected GameShare(int width, int height){
    bounds.setWidth(width);
    bounds.setHeight(height);
}

public Rectangle getBounds(){
    updateBounds();
    return bounds;
}

public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds){
    this.bounds = bounds;
}

public void  updateBounds(){
    bounds.set(position.x, position.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
}

public float getX(){
    return position.x;
}

public float getY(){
    return position.y;
}

public float getVelocityX(){
    return velocity.x;
}

public float getVelocityY(){
    return velocity.y;
}


public Vector2 getPosition() {
    return position;
}



public void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
    this.position = position;
}


public Vector2 getVelocity() {
    return velocity;
}



public void setVelocity(Vector2 velocity) {
    this.velocity = velocity;
}

public float bottom(){
    return bounds.y;
}

public float getHeight(){
    return bounds.height;
}

public float getWidth(){
    return bounds.width;
}

public void Intergrate(float dt){
    position.add((velocity.x * dt), (velocity.y * dt));
}

public float left(){
    return bounds.x;
}

public void move(float x, float y){
    position.set(x, y);
}

public float right(){
    return bounds.x + bounds.width;
}

public void setVelocity(float x, float y){
    velocity.set(x, y);
}

public float top(){
    return bounds.y + bounds.height;
}

public void translate(float x, float y){
    position.add(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `updatePaddle2` method calls `moveTo` on the paddle, which in your code sets the position directly, so it instantly teleports the paddle to a new position -350 units away. Then you call `Intergrate` which doesn't do anything since you haven't set a velocity on the paddle. Since `updatePaddle2` is called on every frame, your paddle is probably flying off the screen at a rate of 350 units per frame * 60 fps = 21,000 units per second.

Based on what it seems like you're trying to do, your method should look something like this, although there seem to be other issues (like why are you updating `paddle1` in the `updatePaddle2` method?).

```
private void updatePaddle2(float dt) {
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched(0)){
        paddle2.setVelocity(-350, 0);
    } else {
        paddle2.setVelocity(0, 0);
    }

    paddle2.Intergrate(dt);
}
```

You'll need to change your `setVelocity` method in your GameShare class to take x and y as arguments instead of a new Vector2. It's wasteful to replace the velocity vector instead of just modifying it.

I also noticed that you don't update the bounds when the position updates in your GameShare class. That's going to cause issues later when you start using the bounds for something. Any place in your code where the position is modified, the bounds' x and y should also be updated to match.